# Teamcity Nuget Restore Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, teamcity, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to build my .net MVC project on teamcity. but getting nuget package restore error. It was working before but suddenly I am getting this error now.

```
  [Step 1/6] restore: Restoring NuGet packages for MyProject.sln (2h:51m:43s)
[13:58:42] :         [restore] NuGet command: C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0\tools\NuGet.exe restore C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\work\5f6306e8bb19f137\MyProject.sln
[13:58:42] :         [restore] Starting: C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script306837631223429769.cmd
[13:58:42] :         [restore] in directory: C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\work\5f6306e8bb19f137
[13:58:42] :         [restore] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 8.0.42078.9
[13:58:42] :         [restore] Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-3.3
[13:58:42] :         [restore] Starting NuGet.exe 3.3.0.212 from C:\JBTeamCity\buildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0\tools\NuGet.exe
[13:58:42] :         [restore] MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Feeds used:
[13:58:43] :         [restore]   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
[13:58:43] :         [restore]   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
[13:58:43] :         [restore]   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
[13:58:43] :         [restore]   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
[13:58:43] :         [restore] 
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Antlr.3.5.0.2.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package AlphaFS.2.0.1.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package AutoMapper.4.0.4.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package bootbox.4.3.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package bootstrap.3.0.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Bootstrap.MVC.EditorTemplates.1.2.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package CommonServiceLocator.1.3.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package EntityFramework.6.1.3.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package EPPlus.4.1.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package ExcelDataReader.3.4.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package ExcelDataReader.DataSet.3.4.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Hangfire.1.5.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Hangfire.Core.1.5.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Hangfire.SqlServer.1.5.0.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.2.0.1.
[13:58:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.2.0.1.
[14:00:23] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '3.5.0.2' of package 'Antlr'.
[14:00:23] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.af.2.0.1.
[14:02:03] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '2.0.1' of package 'AlphaFS'.
[14:02:03] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.ar.2.0.1.
[14:03:43] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '4.0.4' of package 'AutoMapper'.
[14:03:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.bg.2.0.1.
[14:05:23] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '4.3.0' of package 'bootbox'.
[14:05:23] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.bn-BD.2.0.1.
[14:07:03] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '3.0.0' of package 'bootstrap'.
[14:07:03] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.cs.2.0.1.
[14:08:43] :         [restore] WARNING: Unable to find version '1.2.0' of package 'Bootstrap.MVC.EditorTemplates'.
[14:08:43] :         [restore] Restoring NuGet package Humanizer.Core.da.2.0.1.
```

Thanks in advance.